Movie where a group of asian friends kill a bully and their ages are 20-30's
The movie was watched in 2004-6 where I'm pretty sure the main characters were Asian, and the movie is an american one. I am not sure of the genre. 3 or four people plot to beat the shit out of a guy who was a "dick", and allow him to fully recover. They follow through with their plans and beat him up with a baseball bat, but mistakenly paralyze him. After this, they argue on whether to kill him or let him live, and decide to kill him and bury him in someone's lawn. 
The conclusion is a dog digging up his grave and maybe the movie cuts out to the conclusion. Is this enough information to ID the movie?
Additional details:

It was a serious movie;
Watched on a DVD, so I do not know if it was a theater release or indie, but I remember it had decent quality;
It is not Bully.


Hi Dan. Did you watch it on TV? And do you remember the tone (was it supposed to be funny or serious)?

Serious, on a DVD, so i do not know if it was a Theater release or indie, but I remember it had decent quality. It is not Bully.

Sounds like Better Luck Tomorrow, a 2002 Amrican crime drama with an Asian cast.

Ben is a perfectionist and overachiever whose tunnel vision leads to nothing less than graduating at the top of his class. As he struggles to achieve social success, he discovers his darker side. He and his friends: Virgil, Daric and Han lead a double life of mischief and petty crimes to alleviate the pressures of perfection. As their adopted identity grows, the gang tumbles into a downward spiral of excitement, excess and fun. 

They end up beating up Steve, an arrogant rich kid and pretty much the antagonist, with a baseball bat, then suffocate him with gasoline and bury him. He's later dug up, but I'm not sure a dog was involved. The film was based on a real event. Here's the trailer:



